# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:272

Tags: python-3.x

This is my python script:

```
while True:
    text = ""
    img = cam.read()[1]
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    dst = cv2.calcBackProject([imgHSV], [0, 1], hist, [0, 180, 0, 256], 1)
    disc = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(10,10))
    cv2.filter2D(dst,-1,disc,dst)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, (11,11), 0)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(blur, 15)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    thresh = cv2.merge((thresh,thresh,thresh))
    thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
    if len(contours) > 0:
        contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 10000:
            x1, y1, w1, h1 = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            save_img = thresh[y1:y1+h1, x1:x1+w1]
```

This code works properly on another system but while I run it in my system, 
 it shows the following error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:272: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'

Which can be caused by the following script:

```
contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
```

I am using ubuntu 18.02 and opencv 4.0...
This is as part of our project, please help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurring because `cv2.findContours` has changed from V3.X to V4.0 in opencv.
So in V3.X it used to be

`findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy`

Three objects returned.

and V4.0
`findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> contours, hierarchy`

Two objects returned.

So you code would be

`contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]`

if you intend to get contours.